# How to use InstancedBufferGeometry to do raycasting in ThreeJS?

Tags: three.js

There is [an example to show how to raycast using BufferGeometry](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_buffergeometry), but how to do raycast using InstancedBufferGeometry?

For example, add raycasting capability to this demo? 
https://threejs.org/examples/?q=instancing#webgl_buffergeometry_instancing

Answer (score 3):

Raycasting support for meshes with `InstancedBufferGeometry` was never implemented. However, you can use the new [InstancedMesh](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/objects/InstancedMesh) class which was added with `R109` and which does support raycasting. Check out the following example to see this feature in action:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_instancing_raycast

The important raycasting code section looks like so:

```
var intersection = raycaster.intersectObject( mesh ); // mesh is type of InstancedMesh

if ( intersection.length > 0 ) {

    var instanceId = intersection[ 0 ].instanceId;

    mesh.getMatrixAt( instanceId, instanceMatrix ); // get local transformation matrix of the instance
    matrix.multiplyMatrices( instanceMatrix, rotationMatrix ); // modify it
    mesh.setMatrixAt( instanceId, matrix ); // write it back

    mesh.instanceMatrix.needsUpdate = true;

}
```

`three.js R113`

Comment: What is the different purpose for "InstancedBufferGeometry" and "InstancedMesh" each? I am a bit confused, since I saw them being used together, and separately. E.g: examples/webgl_buffergeometry_instancing_interleaved.html They are used together.

Comment: `InstancedBufferGeometry` was the first API in `three.js` used for instanced rendering. However, it was a bit low-level and complicated to use since users always had to enhance shader code on their own. Hence, `InstancedMesh` was introduced so you can use instanced rendering with ordinary geometries and built-in materials. The combination is only necessary if you want to use custom instanced attributes next to the instanced transformation matrix.

Comment: but it looks like if I used `InstancedMesh`, I can only use one material (e.g. color) for all objects in the scene. Is this correct? If I want to used different color,  `InstancedBufferGeometry` is the only choice. Is my understand correct?

Comment: As mentioned in my previous comment, you can combine both classes. In this way, raycasting will work and you don't have to worry about the actual transformation per instance.